# How can I reference an environment variable in TFS build configuration?

Tags: tfs

I have set an environment variable on my system named MSBUILD_HOME that points to the directory that contains the msbuild.exe.

I want to reference this environment variable in the TFS build configuration.  Specifically, I want to reference it in the Build->Advanced->Path to MSBUILD field of an MSBuild configuration step.

I have tried: MSBUILD_HOME, $(MSBUILD_HOME), %MSBUILD_HOME% but nothing works and I've Googled this to death.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!  I just needed to restart the build agent to pick up the changes to the environment.  Using $(MSBUILD_HOME) was the right way to reference it.

Comment: @Greg Prosch, It seems that the solution was not marked:)